# fluendo dvd player installation

Tags: dvd, installed-programs, fluendo

I had purchased Fluendo DVD Player via Ubuntu Software Centre. Since, I have lost my hard drive with all the programmes. Is it possible to renew the programme on a new hard drive again or is the only way to purchase it again?

Comment: is there any trace about you in Ubuntu Software centre?